# My pending change of a .docx file is lost after Visuak Studio hung due to bad internet connection

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community.
The TFS repository is my personal one on Visuak Studio Online.

I just realize my yesterday 6-hour work, a .docx file, is lost.

The connection was bad and it makes Visual Studio hung; I have to close it by a forced application end. Then I retry and commit and get succeeded.

Though the version commited is NOT the oending changes I made yesterday.

Do you have the same issue before? Is there anyway to recover my lost file?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the local copy and don't get an option to "recover" then you're pretty much hosed.

Comment: What do you mean by "being hosed"?

Comment: Sorry, colloquialism. It means there isn't a way to recover them.